# Ant Design's maskClosable modal property is not working?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, antd

I am using ANT Design's modal in another component like so:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Modal,
  Button
} from "antd";

class SomeModalWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  handleOk() {
    console.log("OK");
  }

  render() {
    const { modalVisible, toggleModal } = this.props;

    return (
      <Modal
        title="Some Title"
        visible={modalVisible}
        width={300}
        className=""
        destroyOnClose={true}
        footer={[
          <Button key="back" onClick={() => toggleModal()}>
            Return
          </Button>,
          <Button key="submit" type="primary" onClick={this.handleOk}>
            Submit
          </Button>
        ]}
      >
        // some other content
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

export default SomeModalWrapper;
```

This  component is in turn being called by a parent component like so:

```
import React from "react";

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
        modalVisible: false
    };
  }

  toggleModal() {
    const { modalVisible } = this.state;
    this.setState({ modalVisible: !modalVisible });
  }

  render() {
    const { modalVisible } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
       // some non-modal content     

       <button onClick={() => this.toggleModal()}>Toggle Modal</button>

        <SomeModalWrapper
            modalVisible={modalVisible}
            toggleModal={this.toggleModal}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SomeComponent;
```

All buttons work fine (showing and hiding). However, when I click the area outside the modal, by right, the modal should automatically close as the `maskClosable` property is set to `true` by default. And even if I specifically place it in the modal as `maskClosable: true`, it still doesn't work.

Not sure what's going on? Is it because the modal is wrapped in another component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with `maskClosable` which is [default value is `true`](https://ant.design/components/modal/#API).

1. You need to bind `this` to `toggleModal` function.
2. You set `visible={modalVisible}`, which means you **control** the modal state, with it, `modalVisible` state will **override** `maskClosable`. In other words, `maskClosable` can't change your state by it self.

```js
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    modalVisible: false
  };

  // bind with named class function or with `.bind()` inside consturctor
  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ modalVisible: !prevState.modalVisible }));
  };

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Also, I suggest **always** using `onCancel`, you can get unexpected behavior without it.

```
<Modal
  ...
  onCancel={toggleModal}
  ...
>
  // some other content
</Modal>;
```

[image: Edit styled-antd-react-starter]

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass onCancel props in **SomeWrapper** component : i.e
Somewrapper.js

```
<Modal
        title="Some Title"
        visible={modalVisible}
        width={300}
        className=""
        onCancel={toggleModal} //pass close logic here
        destroyOnClose={true}
        footer={[
          <Button key="back" onClick={() => toggleModal()}>
            Return
          </Button>,
          <Button key="submit" type="primary" onClick={this.handleOk}>
            Submit
          </Button>
        ]}
      >
        // some other content
      </Modal>
```

Here is the demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/long-shape-7tc3g

Comment: Not sure why, I upvoted it. It's the only change I did and it worked.

Comment: It will work but it doesn't explain why `maskClosable` not working, you can see `onCancel` example on every `Modal` example. I downvoted because the question is "maskClosable modal property is not working?" and not "How to make modal work"

Answer (score 1):

Adding this for anyone who made the mistake I did:

I read the documentation for what 'onOk' does which is:

*'Specify a function that will be called when a user clicks the OK button'*

and subconsciously filled in what 'onCancel' does as the opposite of onOk, despite what is actually listed, which is:

'*Specify a function that will be called when a user clicks mask, close button on top right or Cancel button*'.

not only because of my own carelessness, but also because of inconsistent naming in their Api.

---

onCancel should probably be more consistent with naming in components elsewhere in their API such as 'Drawer', where identical functionality is found in the more aptly named property 'onClose', to reduce confusion

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Yohan! I missed this as well, for anyone interested you can find  the original wording in the [Modal API](https://ant.design/components/modal/#API)